# Slim 3 Framework download file not show download dialog

Tags: php, file, download, slim-3

I try download file .png use Slim 3 with this code:

```
$app->get('/api/download/content/image/{filename}', function($request, Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) {
$file = __DIR__ . '/uploads/content/image/'. $args['filename'];
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

$stream = new \Slim\Http\Stream($fh); // create a stream instance for the response body

return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/download')
    ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
    ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"')
    ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
    ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
    ->withBody($stream); });
```

But the download dialog not show. only show string

[Result from Slim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiPLG.png)

Comment: Maybe you have a previous output and headers are not sent.

Comment: Its look like the header change to text. but idk. im not use middleware. how to fix this?

Comment: It can be caused by many reasons, like an space or new line character before <?php tag, print function, echo, etc. You can't send anything to the browser, except the headers and contents of the file.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Thx Triby. its new line before <?php 
you save my day bro